# OWLAPI and HermiT reasoner: can not force irreflexive transitive object property

Tags: java, owl-api, swrl, description-logic, hermit

I am currently using OWLAPI and the HermiT reasoner on a simple ontology `O` modelling delegation.

`O` represents the M.W.E. showing the issue I am facing and defines a single class `Person`, a single object property `delegates(.,.)` (whose domain and range are `Person`) and three individual of type `Person` (A, B and C). Finally, I stated `delegates(A, B)`, `delegates(B, C)`, `delegates(C, A)`.

I am trying to enforce the existence of an irreflexive transitive object property to cause an inconsistency in the ontology when a direct or indirect circular delegation exists.

To the best of my knowledge, this type of property is unsupported since it is non-simple.

I tried to work around this issue defining a SWRL rule of the shape:
`Person(?p), delegates(?p, ?p) -> owl:Nothing(?p)`; however, HermiT DOES NOT identify any inconsistency, despite the fact that transitivity allows to infer that `delegates(A, A)`.

I tried the Pellet reasoner and the ontology is correctly declared inconsistent (after that Protegè badly hangs and the UI becomes inconsistent as well), however in the non-MWE I have so many assertions that the Pellet reasoner is unable to process them in a practical time. This is why I am using HermiT, version `1.4.3.456`. (I also tried the same inference under the latest version `1.4.5.519` with no inconsistency result.)

Any suggestion to cause the inconsistency would be appreciated.

Here is the xml code encoding `O`, I had to remove the ontology and prefix tags to avoid to trigger the `spam filter`.

```
 <Declaration>
      <Class IRI="#Person"/>
 </Declaration>
 <Declaration>
      <ObjectProperty IRI="#delegates"/>
 </Declaration>
 <Declaration>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#A"/>
 </Declaration>
 <Declaration>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#B"/>
 </Declaration>
 <Declaration>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#C"/>
 </Declaration>
 <ClassAssertion>
      <Class IRI="#Person"/>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#A"/>
 </ClassAssertion>
 <ClassAssertion>
      <Class IRI="#Person"/>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#B"/>
 </ClassAssertion>
 <ClassAssertion>
      <Class IRI="#Person"/>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#C"/>
 </ClassAssertion>
 <ObjectPropertyAssertion>
      <ObjectProperty IRI="#delegates"/>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#A"/>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#B"/>
 </ObjectPropertyAssertion>
 <ObjectPropertyAssertion>
      <ObjectProperty IRI="#delegates"/>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#B"/>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#C"/>
 </ObjectPropertyAssertion>
 <ObjectPropertyAssertion>
      <ObjectProperty IRI="#delegates"/>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#C"/>
      <NamedIndividual IRI="#A"/>
 </ObjectPropertyAssertion>
 <TransitiveObjectProperty>
      <ObjectProperty IRI="#delegates"/>
 </TransitiveObjectProperty>
 <ObjectPropertyDomain>
      <ObjectProperty IRI="#delegates"/>
      <Class IRI="#Person"/>
 </ObjectPropertyDomain>
 <ObjectPropertyRange>
      <ObjectProperty IRI="#delegates"/>
      <Class IRI="#Person"/>
 </ObjectPropertyRange>
 <DLSafeRule>
      <Body>
            <ClassAtom>
                 <Class IRI="#Person"/>
                 <Variable IRI="urn:swrl:var#p"/>
            </ClassAtom>
            <ObjectPropertyAtom>
                 <ObjectProperty IRI="#delegates"/>
                 <Variable IRI="urn:swrl:var#p"/>
                 <Variable IRI="urn:swrl:var#p"/>
            </ObjectPropertyAtom>
      </Body>
      <Head>
            <ClassAtom>
                 <Class abbreviatedIRI="owl:Nothing"/>
                 <Variable IRI="urn:swrl:var#p"/>
            </ClassAtom>
      </Head>
 </DLSafeRule>
```

Comment: HermiT inference with SWRL is incomplete for transitive properties. Workaround: you can switch your modelling, i.e. you use an SWRL rule for the transitivity and mark the property as irreflexive.

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser, that definitely did it! I can now avoid circular delegation.